# Error adding JScrollPane to frame?

Tags: java, swing

For the input:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txt,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
       f.setContentPane(scrollPane);
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe `f.setContentPane(scrollPane);` but there isn't much code to rely on.

Comment: i am using jtextpane and wen i add these scrollpane to it it give me  error!

Comment: You'll have to show more code. How is txt created, how is f created - all in good context.

Comment: how can i add complete code in here as i am new to this site?

Comment: JFrame f=new JFrame();
JTextPane txt=new JTextPane();

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  *"how can i add complete code"*  Don't!  Make an MCVE, then add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27670065/edit).

Answer (score -1):

The JscrollPane doesnt take three arguments. It has a argument that requires the parent component (where he scrollpane will be located in GUI).

```
enterJScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txt);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

After you need to add the scroll pane to the GUI.

```
Frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: it does not gives the error anymore but the scroll pane is not shown in the text pane?

Comment: `"The JscrollPane doesnt take three arguments"` -- please re-read JScrollPane API.